# joomla administrator edit own user groups

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

As an Administrator in Joomla, one can add new users and change their user groups, but not to select edit their own groups.
Is there a setting by which administrator can edit their own set of groups? I did not find such in permissions.

I know, this could be achieved by person creating another administrator, and then by that editing the creators groups, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without creating another account?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible without creating a new group, more details https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Users_Groups_Edit

Comment: @Seppo if you have a Joomla question, please ask it on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.   Sincerely, another Seppo.